# after rooting,I cant install some apps regarding to tools and productivity

Tags: micromax-funbook

I have rooted(micromax funbook p280) with root master after I had unrooted my phone with z4root.after rebooting I am facing this problem.on storage it shows ram is full (available 0.00 bytes) after everytime I shut down when power is on it is reseted.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

- Factory Reset Your Device
- If your issue is not resolved than flash the stock ROM with sp flash tools

[HERE](http://androidxda.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool) is the tutorial for flashing stock rom.

> Step 1: Download and install Android USB Drivers on your computer. In case Android USB Drivers are already installed on your Computer then skip this step.
>
> Step 2: Power Off your Android Smartphone and remove the Battery (if it is removable).
>
> Step 3: Download the Stock Rom or Custom Rom that you want to Flash on your Android Smartphone and extract it on your Computer.
>
> Step 4: Download and Extract Smart Phone Flash Tool on Your Computer. After Extracting you will be able to see the following files:
>
> Step 5: Now Open Flash_tool.exe (you will find this from the extracted files in Step#6).
>
> Step 6: Once Smart Phone Flash Tool is launched, Click on the Scatter-Loading Button from the Right.
>
> Step 7: Now, Locate the Scatter File (you will find this file in the Stock Rom or any Custom Rom).
>
> Step 8: Now, Click on the Download Button to begin the Flashing Process.
>
> Step 9: Now, Connect your Smartphone to the Computer using USB Cable (without battery- if it is removable). After connecting the device to the computer Press Volume Down or Volume Up key, so that your computer easily detect your smartphone.
>
> Step 10: Once Flashing is completed, a Green Ring will appear.
>
> Step 11: Close the Smart Phone Flash Tool on your computer and disconnect your Android Smartphone from the computer.
>
> Congratulations, Now your Android Smartphone is successfully running the Stock Rom you have Downloaded.